# Material color changed to pink

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I built a cube under a white point light to build a material using Cycles rendering. When I finished building my material and went to bed after saving the file, the material was kind of white with grey spots.

When I opened the file this morning, the material is pink in color.
Note, I have not made any changes at all to any aspect of the file, anywhere.
So with it just becoming pink for no apparent reason, I have no idea how it happened or what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer in another forum. The pink in my material was the result of a missing texture.

The base texture image could not be found.
I had changed the location of the .blend file prior to opening it to do more work.
I decided to grab the image from where I had it in my Pictures directory and copy it to the same directory as the .blend file and reselect it in the node. The moment I did that, it resummed looking like it should.

Comment: No need to go to other sites, you can use the search box at the top if the page.